# extjs modern NS_ERROR_NOT_AVAILABLE on dialog show()

Tags: javascript, firefox, extjs, dialog, extjs6-modern

I am getting NS_ERROR_NOT_AVAILABLE exception on firefox 60.0.2 on `dialog.show()` of a custom `dialog`.
After debugging I ended up that the exception is being produced on **line 85351** of **ext-modern-all-debug.js:** `value = computedStyle.getPropertyValue(name);` where the property `name` is `opacity` and it is not available inside `computedStyle`.

`[Exception... "Component is not available"  nsresult: "0x80040111 (NS_ERROR_NOT_AVAILABLE)"  location: "JS frame :: debugger eval code :: <TOP_LEVEL> :: line 1"  data: no]`

**Dialog Show Code:**

```
var thisObj = this;

        var wnd = Ext.create('myApp.view.desktop.something.CustomWindow',{

            onButtonSubmitClick: function(){
                thisObj.doSomething();
                this.close();
            }

        });

        wnd.show();
```

**ExtJS Debug Function:**

```
getCssStyleValue: function(name, value) {
    var testElement = this.getTestElement(),
        computedStyle = this.testElementComputedStyle,
        style = testElement.style;
    style.setProperty(name, value);
    if (Ext.browser.is.Firefox) {

        testElement.offsetHeight;
    }
    value = computedStyle.getPropertyValue(name);
    style.removeProperty(name);
    return value;
}
```

Does this bug has to do with [this mozilla bug](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=548397)?

Any workarounds?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know exactly why, but animations were generating this bug. After i set the animations on my `dialog` to:

```
hideAnimation: null,
maximizeAnimation: null,
restoreAnimation: null,
showAnimation: null
```

Everything worked fine.

I hope my answer will help someone with the same issue.